# WebDriver does not dispose

Tags: webdriver, .net-6.0, microsoft-edge, dispose, xunit2

I’m using the Microsoft Edge WebDriver to test inprivate browser windows but I’ve noticed 2 things:

1. WebDriver process does not always end
2. When running more than 1 at a time, taking screenshots often fail once the first web driver has been disposed (the same error is often thrown when calling `driver.Quit()`

My core code follows, but is there a better method to instantiate the driver so that it will clean up properly and be more reliable when running?

```
protected void TestBrowser(string testFilePath, string parameterFile)
{
    var ops = TestEnvironment.BrowserOptions;
    var prof = ops.Arguments[ops.Arguments.Count-1];

    using (var service = TestEnvironment.Service)
    {
        using (var driver = new EdgeDriver(service, ops))
        {
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

            try
            {
                // loop containing Asserts and `driver.FindElements()` etc
            }
            finally
            {
                TakeScreenShot(driver: driver);
                output.WriteLine($"finally {prof}");
                driver?.Quit(); // throws exceptions
                After();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void TakeScreenShot(EdgeDriver driver, string? name = null, Exception? ex = null)
{
    lock (screenShotLock)
    {
        var path = $"{TestName}{ScriptFileName}{ParameterFileName}{new Random().Next(10000}.png";
        driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(path); // throws exception
    }
}

public static EdgeOptions BrowserOptions
{
    get
    {
        lock (optionsLockObj)
        {
            ProfileCounter++;

            var _options = new EdgeOptions();
            _options.LeaveBrowserRunning = false;
            _options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
            _options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";

            if (Directory.Exists($@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\prof-{ProfileCounter}"))
                Directory.Delete($@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\prof-{ProfileCounter}", true);

            _options.AddArgument($@"--user-data-dir={Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\prof-{ProfileCounter}");
            _options.AddArgument($"remote-debugging-port={9222+ProfileCounter}");

            _options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.Debug);

            return _options;
        }
    }
}

public static EdgeDriverService Service
{
    get
    {
        lock (serviceLockObj)
        {
            if (_service is null)
            {
                var _service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"/driver/", @"msedgedriver.exe");
                _service.UseVerboseLogging = true;
                _service.Start();
            }
        }

        return _service;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just use `driver.Close(); driver.Quit();`. What error message do you have? You can also provide feedback on [Edge WebDriver](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver) repo.